# No 'Kotlin Multiplatform' option in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin-multiplatform

I would like to follow along this tutorial: https://ktor.io/docs/getting-started-ktor-client.html#new-project, however, for my installation of IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.3, I don't have the 'Kotlin Multiplatform' option in the new project wizard, as it can be seen on this screenshot (left panel)

[image]

I checked if I have the Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile plugin installed, I didn't, so I searched for it on the Plugins Marketplace, however I couldn't find there:

[image]

Any ideas how to bring this option to IntellijIDEA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things have changed a bit. JetBrains now just has a link to create a Kotlin Multiplatform project, which then takes you to a wizard online at https://kmp.jetbrains.com/

[image: Image shows screenshot of IntelliJ Wizard]